# MongoDB aggregate count based on multiple query fields - (Multiple field count)

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection will look this,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c8bd1d85b83e06dc54c0eb"),
    "name" : "xxx",
    "salary" : 10000,
    "type" : "type1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c8bd1d85b83e06dc54c0eb"),
    "name" : "aaa",
    "salary" : 10000,
    "type" : "type2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c8bd1d85b83e06dc54c0eb"),
    "name" : "ccc",
    "salary" : 10000,
    "type" : "type2"
}
```

My query params will be coming as,

> {salary=10000, type=type2}

so based on the query I need to fetch the count of above query params

**The result should be something like this**,

> { category: 'type1', count: 500 } { category: 'type2', count: 200 } { category: 'name', count: 100 }

Now I am getting count by hitting three different queries and constructing the result (or) server side iteration I can get the result.

Can anyone suggest or provide me good way to get above result

Comment: You would be better of showing what you are currently doing. Your explanation is presently unclear as the the relation of your "params" and the output you say you want.

Comment: @Blakes, My criteria will be or condition(eg. salary>10000, name=xxx) among in this criteria I need to get the count of salary who have passed this criteria and the count of name whom ever have same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quesstion is not very clearly presented, but what it seems you wanted to do here was count the occurances of the data in the fields, optionally filtering those fields by the values that matches the criteria.

Here the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator allows you to tranform a [logical condition](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) into a value:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "name": { "$sum": 1 },
        "salary": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$gte": [ "$salary", 1000 ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "type": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "type2" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

All values are in the same document, and it does not really make any sense to split them up here as this is additional work in the pipeline.

```js
{ "_id" : null, "name" : 3, "salary" : 3, "type" : 2 }
```

Otherwise in the long form, which is not very performant due to needing to make a copy of each document for every key looks like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "salary": 1,
    "type": 1,
    "category": { "$literal": ["name","salary","type"] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$category" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$category",
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$and": [ 
            { "$eq": [ "$category", "name"] },
            { "$ifNull": [ "$name", false ] }
          ]},
          1,
          { "$cond": [
            { "$and": [
              { "$eq": [ "$category", "salary" ] },
              { "$gte": [ "$salary", 1000 ] }
            ]},
            1,
            { "$cond": [
              { "$and": [
                { "$eq": [ "$category", "type" ] },
                { "$eq": [ "$type", "type2" ] }
              ]},
              1,
              0
            ]}
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

And it's output:

```js
{ "_id" : "type",   "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "salary", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "name",   "count" : 3 }
```

If your documents do not have uniform key names or otherwise cannot specify each key in your pipeline condition, then apply with [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/mapReduce/) instead:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var doc = this;
        delete doc._id;

        Object.keys(this).forEach(function(key) {
          var value = (( key == "salary") && ( doc[key] < 1000 ))
              ? 0
              : (( key == "type" ) && ( doc[key] != "type2" ))
              ? 0
              : 1;

          emit(key,value);
        });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
);
```

And it's output:

```js
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "name",
                    "value" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "salary",
                    "value" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "type",
                    "value" : 2
            }
    ]
```

Which is basically the same thing with a conditional count, except that you only specify the "reverse" of the conditions you want and only for the fields you want to filter conditions on. And of course this output format is simple to emit as separate documents.

The same approach applies where to test the condition is met on the fields you want conditions for and return `1` where the condition is met or `0` where it is not for the summing the count.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation it really helped me lot and one more clarification, How can I use "like" condition instead of "equals" in both **mapReduce** and **aggregate** functions.

Comment: @venkat.s The aggregation framework has no such operator for logical comparisons. mapReduce is JavaScript so you can use a regular expression as a logical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) as following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
        $match: {
            salary: 10000,
            //add any other condition here
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$type",
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "category": "$_id",
            "count": 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using aggregate function but I can get the count of any one criteria. I want the count of each criteria fields(eg. salary criteria count, type criteria count )

Comment: As per the question, you can use $facet for multiple aggrigation